# Find directory without files Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have directory tree. How to get list of directories without file xyz.xml using for example batch scripting or Windows browser? 
//If is it possible I want to save list of this directories in Excel file.

I have tried to get answer or tips, there are some for Unix, but I work on Windows 10.

Comment: do you mean empty folders or folders without a special file?

Comment: In case you need to see the list of directories without the files included in those directories, I'd propose the command `tree`. In case you are looking for the directories which contain no files (empty directories), I can't help you.

Comment: sure, I mean directories without special file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the file you want to check for and the root directory at the beginning of the script.

```
@echo off

set "root_dir=."
set "file=xyz.xyz"

for /d /r "%root_dir%" %%# in (*) do (
    if not exist "%%#\%file%" echo %%#
)
```

For not recursive search:

```
@echo off

set "root_dir=."
set "file=xyz.xyz"
pushd "%root_dir%"
for /d   %%# in (*) do (
    if not exist "%%~f#\%file%" echo %%~f#
)
popd
```

Comment: Great, that is what I need! Can you write me how to show only main directory? Without subdirectories.

Comment: @RafałSkowera - yes.Remove the `/r` switch in the for loop

Comment: @RafałSkowera and also `"%root_dir%"` and you'll have to run the file in the directory itself.

Comment: great thats exactly what I need. I removed it, then add `>> result.csv` in loop to open it in excel grid. Thanks!